# GCP Storage API upload files using Java 1.6

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We require to upload files to GCP storage bucket using Java 1.6 version. As storage SDK library support starts with Java 1.7 or above, request to let me know the way forward to operate with GCP storage bucket.

I tried with apache http library by following the guidelines of setting required http header with token however faced issues with oauth token along with refreshing it without using GCP SDK.

Request to provide sample code or any reference to operate on GCP storage bucket using Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been able to see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java), the client library supports Java 7 and above. In addition, the Java version you are trying to use was deprecated more than a year ago as explained in [this post](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2017/10/25/java-6-end-support/). Therefore, I would recommend you to switch either to Java 7 or Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different client libraries available for Google Cloud for Java, but I believe they all require a minimum of Java 7 due to Oracle dropping support for Java 6.

The good news is that Google's OAuth client library for Java seems to only require Java 6. The bad news is that it requires the [Google HTTP for Java library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/), the current version of which requires Java 7. However, that library supported Java 6 until around [only dropped about 6 months ago](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/pull/542), so you could most likely grab an older release and get the OAuth stuff working in Java 6, although I haven't tried.

That wouldn't get you a rich SDK client, but it would at least take care of your OAuth authentication for manually-crafted API requests.

Another option would be to use Google Cloud Storage's compatibility API, the XML API, which works with a variety of third party blob storage clients.